# Nothing shows in my kendo ui grid when i try to add a template or custom command

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, command

I've made a kendo grid and i'm trying to make a Custom command that links to another site passing a variable that is the same as a value from that row (a int). When i add a custom command with:

```
columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Info").Text("info").Click("orderinfo"); }).Width(140);
```

nothing shows up in the grid, only the headers of each column. I also tried to solve the problem by just making row elements clickable by using a template, but this gives me the same problem. I've tried using: `columns.clientTemplate`, `columns.Template` and `.clientRowTemplate`.

Anyone know why nothing shows up in the grid anymore when i try to add something like this?

Comment: Are there any JS errors? Sometimes the easiest way to debug these problems is to grab the JS generated by the MVC Helper out of your page and use that instead of the helper.

Comment: I sort of made a working fix for what i wanted to do, i made the row selectable and made a event when you select the row to redirect to a page passing a row id. i don't really like this solution, but it does the job.